# Read out Double and DateTime from NOSQL Database

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, double

I want to read out a double and date from a SQLite Database with C#.

**Database:**

- date: numeric
- money: real

**Code:**

```
SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = " + nameDB + ".sqlite; Version = 3;");
dbConnection.Open();

String sql = $"SELECT * FROM banking";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, dbConnection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("date: " + Convert.ToDateTime( reader["date"]) );
    Console.WriteLine("money: " + reader["money"]);
}

dbConnection.Close();
```

The problem is in my database data is this:

```
date: 28.06.2017 14:45:24
money: 20,50
```

And my output was this:

```
reader[date]: 28,06
reader[money]: 20
```

Ho can i say the reader to read the `money` as `double` and `date` as `DateTime` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("money"));
reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("date"))
```

refer to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitedatareader?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0) for all the available methods for `SqliteDataReader`

Comment: Thanks this works. I find my problem: sometimes the database save the real numbers with comma instead a point. This gives the error of a wrong format

Answer (score 0):

Use Parse methods for `double` and `DateTime`. Try like:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    var date =DateTime.Parse(reader["date"].ToString());
    var money = double.Parse(reader["money"].ToString("0.##"));
}
```

Comment: for the date it works, but the money has no decimal numbers after the decimal point

Comment: @Gh0stscript, Edited please try again

Comment: there i get the error "No overload for ToString method takes 1 arguments"